# htaccess links redirect doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess

I have a problem with redirecting categori links in htacess file
can you check what I am missing please 
news links works but category links dont.

I would like to redirect links wit htaccess

```
Category link example:
    site url/3159-economi.html
```

```html
// Catogory Original link
    cats.php?id=catid

// Catogory Seo link 
$news_url_seo = $row[catid]."-".seo($row[category]);

// News Original link
  details.php?id=id

// News seo link
 $news_url_seo = $anews[id]."-".seo($anews[title]).".html";
```

Htaccess links

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)-(.*).html$ details.php?id=$1&$title=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-(.*)$ news.php?catid=$1&$category=$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: It seems unclear, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: when I click category link it goes like this : /catid-catname but list nothing in category

Comment: Please provide your original urls and your desired urls too it is hard to make assumption.

Comment: `// Category Original link
    cats.php?id=catid

// Category Seo link 
$news_url_seo = $row[catid]."-".seo($row[category]);`

Comment: the second submask means `$2`. Do precise the regexp, eg `^(\d+)-(\w+)\.html$`

Comment: I have 2 different files : details.php (which is showing news details). and news.php (which is showing category with news in). news details works but category news.php dont work htacces link dont redirect it to news.php, redirecting to deatils.php and dont list category. here is my htaccess flie : `RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(\d+)-(\w+)\.html$ news_detail.php?id=$1&$title=$2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(\d+)-(\w+)\.html$ news.php?cid=$1&$category=$2 [L,NC]` @Deadooshka 19

Comment: you specified "Catogory Seo link" without ".html", thus remove it from the second rule: `^(\d+)-(\w+)$ news.php?cid=$1&category=$2`